# How do I modify a node's body (or any field) on display as `hook_node_view`?

Tags: hooks, 8

So I am trying to upgrade my modules from Drupal 7 to 8 and some things have been pretty straightforward so far, but I'm stuck at a particular function that I just can't figure out how to implement on Drupal 8. Figuring out exactly how to make these changes on 7 was difficult enough, involving a lot of playing around with `print_r`. Maybe my approach last time was not the right way and therefore I'm already on the wrong track for Drupal 8. Anyway, I was trying to do a find and replace on node body text to change a pattern into a node URL. The code is below:

```
 function textreplace_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
   if($node->type == "article"){
     if(empty($node->content['body'])) return $node;
     $text = $node->content['body'][0]['#markup'];
     $offset = 0;
     $m = array();
     while ( preg_match('/\{\{nodeurl-([0-9]+)\}\}/', $text, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset) ) {
       $offset = $m[0][1] + strlen($m[0][0]);
       $nod = (explode("-", str_replace("{{","",str_replace("}}","",$m[0][0]))));
       $nod = $nod[1];
       $thenode = node_load($nod);
       $text = str_replace($m[0][0], l($thenode->title, 'node/' . $nod), $text);
     }
     $node->content['body'][0]['#markup'] = $text;
     return $node;
   }
 }
```

I tried looking at how it was implemented in the Book module and the parameters started giving me errors when I changed them to what I saw in the Book module:

```
function book_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
```

I was getting an error along the lines of `$node` must be of type EntityInterface...

Any help?

Comment: You should use input format for this.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! When you changed your code and got that _`$node` must be of type `EntityInterface`_, was `$node` still the first agument of the hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you are changing $build, which you don't need to return:

```
function textreplace_node_view(&$build, $node, $display, $view_mode) {
  // your code for $text
  $build['body'][0]['#text'] = $text;
}
```

Comment: Worth checking out https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x

Comment: Hi am using the hook_node_view as **function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {** How to modify a field when using like this ? any idea ?